# Доступ к файлу по оносительнуму пути к каталогу resources

Tags: java, maven, classloader

обычный многомодульный проект с maven.

В каталоге test, есть каталог resources в котором находятся файлы с xml.

При запуске тестов, я пытаюсь получить доступ к файлу xml

```java
String path = "ДТ/528605A0-0A48-0205-0000-5598EB317C92-59951996_DT.xml";

    private InputStream getMessage(String path) {

         URL resource = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("./soap/" + path);

        String pathToXml = resource.toString();

        File file = new File(pathToXml);


        try {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            return fileInputStream;

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to read xml-file.");
    }
```

Но в отладке, я вижу что он  захватывает вот такой путь

```java
file:/E:/!_svn/project/customs.import/target/test-classes/soap/DT/528605A0-0A48-0205-0000-5598EB317C92-59951996_DT.xml
```

и получается exception.

A файл расположен

```java
src/main/test/resources/soap/DT/528605A0-0A48-0205-0000-5598EB317C92-59951996_DT.xml
```

Я в основной части проекта установил каталог **resources** и положил туда файл по указанному пути.
 Когда запускаются тестовые классы, среда разработки копирует нужный файл по указанному пути в target/classes

Я в отладочном режиме вижу путь к файлу

```java
file:/E:/!_svn/project/customs.import/target/test-classes/soap/%d0%94%d0%a2/528605A0-0A48-0205-0000-5598EB317C92-59951996_DT.xml
```

но снова exception

```java
 (Синтаксическая ошибка в имени файла, имени папки или метке тома)
```

Как можно нормально прочитать файлы из относительного пути.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3803326/this-getclass-getclassloader-getresource-and-nullpointerexception

Comment: так я же код и взял оттуда, для получения пути к файлу. Вы нашли ответ на мой вопрос по указанному пути ? Так подскажите куда обратить внимание, возможно я невнимателен.

Comment: Не используйте `./` , без него должно работать